# Proving that finite, connected group schemes in characteristic 0 are trivial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-groups

I have a question about a specific proof that all finite group schemes in characteristic 0 are etale. The proof is [here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Easnowden/teaching/2013/679/L05.html), Proposition 8 in lecture notes by Andrew Snowden.

In his notation, let $A = k\oplus I$ be a (finite) local group scheme over a field $k$. For now, we are agnostic about the characteristic of the field. Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be elements in $I$ that form a basis for $\Omega_{A/k} = I/I^2$. He defines derivations $D_i: A \to A$ by $A \to A\otimes A \to A \otimes I/I^2 \to A$ where the first map is the comultiplication map, the second map is projection on the second factor and the third map sends $x_i \to 1$ and the other $x_j \to 0$ in the second factor.

He claims in the proof of the proposition that $D_i(x_i) = 1$ but I don't see why this has to be true. Let us do an example: Take $A = k[t]/(t-1)^p = \operatorname{Spec} \mu_p$ in characteristic $p$ and we can take $n=1,x_1 = t-1$. Then the comultiplication map sends $x_1 \to x_1\otimes x_1 + x_1\otimes 1 + 1\otimes x_1$ and so $D_1(x_1) = x_1+1$ if I did the computation right.

**Question 1:** Where did I go wrong?

**Question 2:** How do I geometrically interpret this proof? What is the $D_i$ doing and why do they only exist for group schemes? I have seen other geometrically motivated proofs of this fact but I don't understand this one.

Comment: Wait, doesn't comultiplication in $\mu_n = \operatorname{Spec} k[x_1]/(x_1^n - 1)$ send $x_1$ to $x_1 \otimes x_1$, including if $p \mid n$?  That seems to give $D_1 \colon x_1 \mapsto x_1 \otimes x_1 \mapsto x_1 \otimes x_1 \mapsto x_1 \otimes 1 = x_1$, which still isn't $D_1(x_1) = 1$, as you say even in characteristic $0$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say $ x_1 = t - 1$, the x_i have to lie in I

Comment: on a group scheme $G$, the $D_i$ are the derivatives along the $G$-invariant vector fields on $G$. You can see that from the construction as we can take the invariant derivative of a function $f$ at a point $g$ by taking the derivative of $f(g_1g_2)$ at $(g,e)$ in the $g_2$ direction. $f(g_1g_2)$ is the comultiplication, taking the derivative in the $g_2$ direction is the second step, and then specializing to a give tangent vector is the last step. I think the proof is supposed to be doing something like exponentiating the vector fields.

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks, that's along the lines of what I was thinking but I didn't quite get there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand that claim either.

It seems to me that if you follow the chain rule you get $$D_i (\varphi(f)) = \sum_{j=1}^n D_i(x_j) \varphi \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j } \right). $$ You have  $D_i(x_j) \equiv \delta_{ij} \mod I$  so the matrix with entries $D_i(x_j)$ is invertible which means if $D_i (\varphi(f))=0$ for all $i$ then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}=0$ for all $j$ which again means that the kernel of $\varphi$ is invariant under $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$ and you can continue from there.

Comment: Great, I think that works!